# How can i monitor and pass variables in azure data factory foreach activity?

Tags: azure, validation, azure-data-factory, azureportal

I'm following this guide:
https://medium.com/geekculture/create-an-array-of-dates-for-looping-in-azure-data-factory-da148e01bc10

When i have set it up and try to pass the variable into the next forEachStatment i dont understand how it should work.

[image: Img: Pipeline with variable]

Inside the last ForEach i have a copy activity to copy a file from a URL that has a dynamic filename based on date, and i try to get the array-element from the array and insert into the RelativeUrl, but it does now work for me:
[image: copy activity]

[image: Relative URL - dynamic expression]

**1. How can i monitor the array 'daystoiterateover' content ?**

**2. How do i pass it on to my next forEach loop?** I tried to access it by @item in a Realative URL, but it is not recognized.

Additional info, the foreach "item" is accessible in dynamic expression when choosing the "Request Method" on the CopyData activity (indicating its created):
[image]

Comment: I found out that to use it in RelativeUrl of the sink, i need to define/link the variables as "dataset variables". "Relative URL @dataset().relativeURLs". Still i wonder how i can monitor the content of the output array of the first ForEach function thouth.. ?

Answer (score 0):

- It seems that you are trying to use the dynamic content `@item()` in the dataset of the copy activity. And hence it is not recognized within the dataset. The following is the image of same warning message when I tried to replicate this behavior.

[image]

- However, as long as this pipeline is not used in any other pipeline (at least ones which are not similar to current pipeline), then this warning message would not matter.

[image]

- So, you can pass the value as it is to the 2nd for each loop and use it in the same way. To monitor, you can use the set variable activity and monitor its value over each iteration.

Comment: By "variable activity", do you mean "Append variable" or "Set variable", and does it display values during "Debug" triggering of  the pipeline?

Comment: Its set variable activity, and yes, it displays values during debug